# Microsoft.Rest.HttpOperationException in Microsoft.Bot.Builder.dll ("Access Denied") while testing PromptDialog.Confirm

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm trying to test the IDialog Flow with a fake Message so:

```
        var toBot = new Message()
        {
            ConversationId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            Text = "Test",
        };

        Func<IDialog<T>> MakeRoot = () => testDialog;
        toBot.From = new ChannelAccount(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        toBot.To = new ChannelAccount(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
```

When it hits the PromptDialog.Confirm, it throws the "Microsoft.Rest.HttpOperationException in Microsoft.Bot.Builder.dll ("Access Denied")" exception.

If I don't create

```
        toBot.From = new ChannelAccount(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
```

it throws System.NullReferenceException for ChannelId.

PromptDialog.Confirm looks like this:

```
    PromptDialog.Confirm(context, AfterErrorConfirmationAsync, Strings.ConfirmError,
                Strings.InvalidInput);
```

How can I work around this issue?

Answer (score 2):

The issue was caused by this:

```
    await context.PostAsync(replyMessage);
    PromptDialog.Confirm(context, AfterErrorConfirmationAsync, Strings.ConfirmError,
            Strings.InvalidInput);
```

Having a confirm dialog immediately after posting a message to the user caused the exception and subsequently test failure. It did not throw this exception during run time though.

I resolved the above issue by combining the reply message with the confirmation string as follows:

```
    PromptDialog.Confirm(context, AfterErrorProcessingAsync, replyMessage + "\n\n" + Strings.ConfirmError,
                Strings.InvalidInput);
```

Leaving this question open if someone has a better workaround.